# Sphinx 'failed to create process.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-sphinx

I have an issue while using the command sphinx-quickstart.
I get the following message :

> failed to create process

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please add some of the code and a more detailed description?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added an image of the terminal command I used

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the python script rather than the executable. Should be something  like:

```
python C:\Python27\Scripts\sphinx-quickstart-script.py
```

Probably you are getting an error that now will show up.